# Xcode Debug Shortcuts

Tags: xcode4

How can I go step by step in Xcode while debugging with a keyboard shortcut? I'd like to make step over and step into with the keyboard, I've looked for keysheets and such but didn't find keys for that particular actions.

Comment: F6 step over, F7 step into, F8 step out

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This is an easy one indeed. Go to `Xcode`>`Preferences`>`Key Bindings` and search for '`step`'. There you can define your shortcuts for each action.

PS: As @Jenn noted below "Pause/Continue" is missing from this list, which is by default bound to <kbd>⌃⌘Y</kbd> (ctrl + command + Y)

[image: XCode Key Bindings]

Comment: The "Continue program execution" is called "Pause / Continue" in the key bindings list (so you won't see it if you search for "step"). By default it is ⌃⌘Y (ctrl + command + Y)

Comment: @Jenn Good observation, I'll amend accordingly. Thanx :)

Comment: You can enable the function buttons (F6,F7,F8...etc.) by going to `Mac System Preferences->Keyboard` and checking the box for `"Use all F1,F2,etc. keys as standard function keys"`

Answer (score 19):

See this cheat sheet about Xcode keyboard shortcuts:

**UPDATE**:

There are many good resources to know Xcode shortcut.
I am listing some of here:

- Shortcuts of Xcode & Simulator with demo : [Xcode Shortcuts the iOS Cheat Sheet](https://mobidevtalk.com/xcode-shortcuts-cheat-sheet/)
- Xcode Cheat Sheet by Git Tower : [xcode-cheat-sheet-detail](https://www.git-tower.com/blog/xcode-cheat-sheet)
- Very in depth detail about Xcode shortcut: [Xcode Efficiency Tips: Keyboard Shortcuts](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/23/xcode-keyboard-shortcuts/)
- One more detail article on this with animation: [Becoming the Xcode Power User](http://www.pasanpremaratne.com/2014/05/16/becoming-an-xcode-power-user/)
- Apple Official document for Xcode: [About Xcode Gestures and Keyboard Shortcuts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_help-command_shortcuts/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- One good overview of Xcode shortcut: [Xcode 6 Keyboard Shortcuts](https://s3.amazonaws.com/iphonedev.tv/14+Xcode+Keyboard+Shortcuts+Cheat+Sheet.pdf)
- Simple shortcuts list: [Xcode Keyboard Shortcuts](https://swifteducation.github.io/assets/pdfs/XcodeKeyboardShortcuts.pdf)
- Shortcut Explain with animation: [My Favorite Xcode 8 Shortcuts](https://medium.com/ios-geek-community/bobs-favorite-xcode-8-shortcuts-part-1-3-36381e07284d)
- Some shortcuts to improve speed: [17 Xcode Tips and Tricks](https://www.detroitlabs.com/blog/2017/04/13/17-xcode-tips-and-tricks-that-every-ios-developer-should-know/)

I know this is not the direct answer to the question. The Direct answer is already been give by Alladinian. But I think this answer is served as a good resource who is interested in Xcode shortcuts.

**OLD ANSWER**
[image]

NOTE:

- Visit this link for PDF version: [Xcode 4.0 Keyboard Shortcuts (Blue)](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/Machx/Xcode-Keyboard-Shortcuts/Xcode_Shortcuts.pdf)
- If any one is interested in updating this for Xcode 5.x then visit original GitHub repo: [Xcode Keyboard Shortcuts](https://github.com/Machx/Xcode-Keyboard-Shortcuts)

Comment: This is nice, but barely readable. Do you have a link to the original image, or even better a PDF?

Comment: this image is already in good quality (2088 X 2160) just open it in new tab or open after save.

Comment: Yup. It's just not clear, as it's not clickable. You should at least mention it in your answer, something like "original image is huge". Now it's done ;)

Comment: Here's a clearer version without jpeg compression artifacts: http://www.1729.us/xcode/Xcode%20Shortcuts.png

Comment: @Dermot Thanks for this improvement.

Comment: This does not answer the question, the default shortcuts for step over (F6) and step into (F7) are not in this cheatsheet.

Comment: It would be nice to see an updated version of this for the current default key bindings. Even I stopped mapping XCode to these old keys eventually...

Comment: @Echelon Thanks to point out me to update. Original author update it for Xcode 4 so I put that updated version. He also make it public on Github so if someone want to make it more up to date he can help there.

Answer (score 4):

Apples website has an easy to read list:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_help-command_shortcuts/MenuCommands/MenuCommands014.html

Specifically F6 to step over and F7 to step into are the ones I use the most.